# Generic method for retriving a single object c#

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

I've been looking at this method for a while now and trying to figure out how it works. This clearly works for returning a list of objects just perfect. But what I can't currently figure out is how I would retrive a single object for instance "Employee e" and not "List"?

```
public static List<T> DataTableToList<T>(this DataTable table) where T : class, new()
{
    try
    {
        List<T> list = new List<T>();

        foreach (var row in table.AsEnumerable())
        {
            T obj = new T();

            foreach (var prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
            {
                try
                {
                    PropertyInfo propertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name);
                    propertyInfo.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(row[prop.Name], propertyInfo.PropertyType), null);
                }
                catch
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }

            list.Add(obj);
        }

        return list;
    }
    catch
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can always get the object from the List itself.  I don't think that's what you're asking, though.  Are you wanting to know to retrieve a row as object from a DataTable?

Comment: There is already `First/FirstOrDefault` available which can be applied to any `IEnumerable<T>`, you can apply that on your returned list.

Comment: I am having trouble imagining what part of returning a single object is difficult to understand.  Can you edit your question to outline your thinking?

Comment: You can't return both a list and a single object from a method without resorting to `object`.  Either have a second method that returns a single instance or live with returning a list that _contains_ one object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just call

```
var employee = table.DataTableToList<Employee>().FirstOrDefault();
```

Alternatively (if your `DataTable` is very large), you might want to modify your extension method to return an `IEnumerable<T>` instead, using the `yield` keyword:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> DataTableToList<T>(this DataTable table) where T : class, new()
    {
        try
        {
            foreach (var row in table.AsEnumerable())
            {
                T obj = new T();

                foreach (var prop in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        PropertyInfo propertyInfo = obj.GetType().GetProperty(prop.Name);
                        propertyInfo.SetValue(obj, Convert.ChangeType(row[prop.Name], propertyInfo.PropertyType), null);
                    }
                    catch
                    {
                        continue;
                    }
                }

                yield return obj;
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            yield break;
        }
    }
```

The advantage of this is that the method will only convert as many rows of the table as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Just call FirstOrDefault with a lamba experession on the List that this method returns.

So if you are looking for a specific Employee instance and you have an Id property on that object you would do something like.

var employee = employeeTableInstance.DataTableToList().FirstOrDefault(e => e.Id.Equals(id));

this is not the most efficient way to pluck a single object because it requires you map the entire table from row instances to object instances, but if you still need the table to list functionality for other reasons and are likely to call it anyway, then you could take this approach.

If you don't need that then I would look at either call the DataRowCollection's Find method if you are searching by Primary Key or looking into a query expression and then just mapping the one row instead of all rows.  Examples of Find and Query Expression can be found here.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y06xa2h1.aspx